# Where can I buy knife-edges for a guitar tremolo bridge?

Tags: electric-guitar, tremolo-system, tremolo

I recently discovered that I need to replace the edge-knives on my chrome black EDGE III tremolo but I cannot find them on the Ibanez website nor on Ebay. Could anyone tell me where to buy them (online or in a shop)?

P.S. I live in Brussels, Belgium

Answer (score 5):

I don't believe that they are individually replaceable.  I think you will have to order a complete replacement tremolo.

See [this site](http://www.ibanezrules.com/tech/setup/tuning_stability.htm), which says:

> The knife edges of the trem become worn or damaged and require filing to get back to a proper knife edge. This is also rarely seen on
>   Edge variants [except Edge3!] and some "mating" of the parts is
>   actually preferred as they form to each other, and their specific use.
>   Cheaper trems are more prone to wear. The same procedure as fixing a
>   fat/flat knife edge, see this section to walk you through shaping the
>   knives. Note, you do NOT want the knives sharp. **You cannot replace
>   knife edges if you screw them up or they're shot, Ibanez refuses to
>   sell them**, or the trem baseplates alone, you need to replace the
>   bridge at that point.

Here is the [knife edge-sharpening](http://www.ibanezrules.com/tech/setup/sharpening.htm) page mentioned.

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps you'll have to order a new base plate.

Some people try to resharp their, but it has to be really well done, and will probably affect the intonation.

Comment: Fabio - this doesn't add anything over the existing answer.